# Logstash - will an input from amazon's redis as a service work with logstash's redis input plugin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, logstash, amazon-elasticache

will an input from amazon's redis as a service work with logstash's redis input plugin?

Basically is the amazon redis as a service simply a cluster of redis or a wrapper (in which case the plugin might not work)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are asking if Redis/ElastiCache can function as a [broker](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/tutorials/getting-started-with-logstash) in a centralized logstash installation. It may be working but ElastiCache is designed to be a cache which is a different from the architectural pattern of a broker. A good fit is AWS SQS for which logstash provides an input as well as an output plugin. A sample pipe:

```
architectural view:
logstash shipper --> broker/queue --> logstash indexer         --> database/storage
example:
webserver logs   --> SQS queue    --> logstash on EC2 instance --> elasticsearch on EC2 instance
```